# grunt concant slowing computer down

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

Basically I have a directory with 8 js files. I want them concated into one main.js file whenever either of them are edited. Just running `grunt watch` slows down computer so much that I can no longer do much of anything. Right click is taking 30+ seconds. Web pages isn't reloading etc.

Why is happening? Is there any other way to do this. I don't want to manually write grunt concat each time I make tiny change in one of my js files.

I'm on windows 7 64 bit.

Comment: What's your watch expression ? Share grunt code

Comment: Its basically 'src/*.js' to 'public/main.js'

Comment: After upgrading node to 0.12, I am also getting 100% CPU usage with watch... dont know what to do.. Searched for issues on grunt-contrib-watch but couldnt find anything that solves the problem...